# Google Sheet API - How to copy/paste an entire sheet to another spreadsheet?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a production spreadsheet and a development spreadsheet.

I need to copy the first sheet of production file into development file.

I cannot understand the usage of [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) because there is not way to se the destination.

How to copy a sheeet from one sheet to another?

### IMPORTANT

I am using PHP !

Comment: When I saw your question, from your tags of `google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api`, I understood that you wanted to achieve your goal using Sheets API with Google Apps Script. But, now I noticed that from your current question and tags, I understood that my proposed answer was not useful for your question. So I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PHP, please refer to [Google Sheets PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) to learn how to setup and use Google Sheets API in PHP.

**Sample code to copy a sheet to a different spreadsheet using [spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo):**

```
  $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
  $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest();
  $requestBody->setDestinationSpreadsheetId($destinationSpreadsheetId);
  $response = $service->spreadsheets_sheets->copyTo($originalSpreadsheet, $sheetId, $requestBody);
```

---

### **Explanation:**

- Assuming you were able to successfully create an authorized API client, by following the PHP Quickstart Guidelines, You need to create a Sheet service using [Class Google_Service_Sheets](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets.html). You need to provide the API client in the constructor.
- Create a request body for [spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) request, by creating a
  [Class Google_Service_Sheets_CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_CopySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequest.html) object. Then set the destinationId using `setDestinationSpreadsheetId($destinationSpreadsheetId)` method
- Call the [spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo) and provide the required path parameters and the request body

### **Additional References:**

- [Google APIs Client for PHP documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php)
- [Google Sheets API PHP reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/index.html)

Comment: Where did you find documented the use of `setDestinationSpreadsheetId()` ?

Comment: Here [Google Sheets API PHP reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/index.html) it contains all sheets api classes for php

Comment: Well, ok, the doc, but no example. Bad documentation by Google